# CodeHS: How use one class's toString method in another class's toString multiple times

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, return, tostring

This exercise is asking us to make a "RoadTrip" class that creates an ArrayList of geolocations using a geolocation class. Part of the exercise asks that we make a toString method within the RoadTrip Class that would end up returning a string like:

```
1. San Francisco (37.7833, -122.41671)
2. Los Angeles (34.052235, -118.2436831)
3. Las Vegas (36.114647, -115.1728131)
```

making a string for each of the GeoLocation objects within the ArrayList.

But I cannot put the return statement in a for loop. Here's an example of me "cheating" to get it do simulate what I would want it do actually do.

```
public String toString() 
    {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size() ; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(counter + ". " + locationList.get(i).toString());
            counter++;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

If I were to simply replace the `System.out.println()` with `return` and remove the `return "";`, I would get the errors:

```
RoadTrip.java:43: error: unreachable statement
            counter++;
            ^
RoadTrip.java:45: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
2 errors
```

I saw other solutions that would utilize a StringBuilder, but I am assuming that the creators of the curriculum intend that we complete the exercises with the tools we are provided. Is there another method that I can use that would limit itself to the given "toolset"?

Pardon me if my techincal language is off, I'm still relatively new to coding.

Comment: If you want to avoid `StringBuilder`, you will have to concat `String` in for loop which is an anti-pattern. Are you sure that `StringBuilder` is not in your "toolset"?

Comment: So...Any progress so far?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to complete the assignment by concatenating a string. Sorry I forgot to inform you!

Answer (score 1):

### Why the problem happens-

1. The control encounters the return statement on the first loop iteration  and goes back to where the method was called from. Hence the following lines in the loop body are not reachable.
2. Since the return statement is within a loop and is subject to conditional execution, the compiler tells you there is a missing return statement. See code below:

```java
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method());
    }
    static int method()
    {
        int i= (int)Math.random();
        if(i>0)
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Since this is *your assignment* I won't be providing working code.

The easiest solution would be to define a String variable, store an empty String (`""`) in it, concat whatever you need in the loop and `return` it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the reason behind my problem. The help's much appreciated.

Comment: "The help's much appreciated."

An upvote to show it would be really nice.  :P

Comment: My upvotes aren’t visible until I get more reputation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use StringBuilder, why not concatenate Strings like this;

```
public String toString() 
    {
        int counter = 1;
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size() ; i++) 
        {
            str = str + counter + ". " + locationList.get(i).toString();
            str = str + "\n";
            counter++;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

P.S - I didn't run the code.

Comment: Wow, that was such an obvious solution. I can't believe I forgot about "\n" too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: String str= null;
    str = str + "100";
    System.out.println(str);

will print "null100"